# Accessing a Windows 7 print share without a password

Tags: active-directory, windows-7, print-server

In our network we have a Windows 7 print server. Users connect to this machine by typing `\\server_name` on their own workstations. The print server and the users` computers are members of Active Directory. In AD, only computers have accounts, users are using local accounts.

Is it possible to configure Windows 7 so that it doesn't ask for login and password when a user tries to access it from computer which is member of domain?

Comment: Why would you configure AD in this way?

Comment: Don't try to print via SMB.  Setup IPP/LPR or some other sharing protocol?

Comment: I second what @Shads0 says. Why the hell are users logging in with local accounts on domain-joined computers? That's ridiculous.

Comment: @Shads0 We don't use domain account because we don't need them. Most of network environment is based on Linux. AD is used only for remote Management of workstations south  as running startup scripts, software management etc...

Comment: @user101141 based on your question, it sure sounds like you need them to me.

Comment: @user101141 You don't need "the Active Directory" but you should implemet some "Directory Service" around according to your requeriments.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have AD implemented, you're better off saving yourself a lot of other headaches in the future by giving the users accounts on the domain instead of locally and having them log in this way.  The benefits of this vastly outweigh any other type of pieced together solution that is not supported by Microsoft in the firstplace.

Answer (score 0):

The user would have to logon with an AD/network account.  Alternatively, you could recreate each users' local user account on the print server (username and password MUST match).  In short, not possible.

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong but it is not possible.

User must be members of the domain to log or access computer of the domain.

With Windows 7, you might be able to store password with the credential manager but still the account need to be a active directory user account.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a user entry in the directory, granting that user to access print server shares, then saving that user's cridentials to all clients should be a solution.

Edit from comments:

When local user tries to access that win7 share, o.s. will perform a login screen. That local user could type the credentials of the user, which you created and edited its permissions of that specific share, and save that information clicking "Remember bla bla".

By doing that, creating a user and cridential saving,

1. You can have some control over that share.
2. Local users won't be have to type that user-password info all the time.

Comment: What does this even mean? `"then saving that user's credentials to all clients"` That doesn't even make sense.

Comment: Maybe I let that open ended.

*Clients trying to access the share
*A login box appears
*User enters credentials
*User can save cridentials